# Youtube API: get the autoplay list of a track

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Youtube has this new awesome feature allowing the autoplay a next track.

[image: Youtube autoplay]

Any chance this automatic playlist could be queried through the youtube API v3?

Thanks