# "Next track" function of youtube-api works wierd

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was trying to implement something like "playlist generator" in Java (similar thread: [Youtube API: get the autoplay list of a track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040915/youtube-api-get-the-autoplay-list-of-a-track)). Simply, tool which for some input phase performs communication to the Youtube.com v3 API generating sequence of videos of specified length.

It is working following way:

1. The input is search phase.
2. It is performed search request by invoking:

   ```
   YouTube.Search.List req = youtube.search().list("snippet");
   req.setType("video");
   req.setMaxResults(1l);
   req.setQ(phase);
   ```
3. From the response it is extracted first video and its videoID.
4. There is requested "Up next" video by request:

   ```
   YouTube.Search.List req = youtube.search().list("snippet");
   req.setType("video");
   req.setRelatedToVideoId(id);
   ```
5. Steps 3 and 4 are repeated specified times (for instance 10x).
6. The result is list of videos collected.

When I run this with input "progressive house mix", I get following sequence of videos (lines contains videoID, title and length):

```
2SVQ1LYElnY, ♫ Best Progressive House Mix 2018 Vol. #5 ♫, 1:54:32
KvRVky0r7YM, Progressive House · Relaxing Focus Music · 24/7 Live Radio, 0:00
VnzIsEgSrCE, Beautiful Piano Music LIVE 24/7: Instrumental Music for Relaxation, Study, Stress Relief, 0:00
3NycM9lYdRI, Relaxing Piano Music: Romantic Music, Beautiful Relaxing Music, Sleep Music, Stress Relief ★122, 3:36:39
y7e-GC6oGhg, Beautiful Piano Music 24/7: Study Music, Relaxing Music, Sleep Music, Meditation Music, 0:00
hlWiI4xVXKY, Beautiful Relaxing Music - Peaceful Piano Music & Guitar Music by Soothing Relaxation, 3:03:39
y7e-GC6oGhg, Beautiful Piano Music 24/7: Study Music, Relaxing Music, Sleep Music, Meditation Music, 0:00
hlWiI4xVXKY, Beautiful Relaxing Music - Peaceful Piano Music & Guitar Music by Soothing Relaxation, 3:03:39
y7e-GC6oGhg, Beautiful Piano Music 24/7: Study Music, Relaxing Music, Sleep Music, Meditation Music, 0:00
hlWiI4xVXKY, Beautiful Relaxing Music - Peaceful Piano Music & Guitar Music by Soothing Relaxation, 3:03:39
```

As you can see, it starts to loop after a few videos loaded. In some cases it repeates only two videos even from the beggining.

IMHO it is caused by Youtube thinking "Oh, so you want this video? Okay, here you are." followed by "Oh, you didn't liked it because it's beeing less than a second and you want another one? Okay, here it is!" and then "Oh, you don't like that either? Well it seems I cannot satisfy you, why am I even trying something? Wouldn't you like to simply try the previous video again, would you? Maybe you changed your mind." which then loops.

I remember, it once happened to me while playing over youtube website, so it makes sense for me a bit. But I didn't expect to happen it **allways**.

My question is simple - do you have any explanation of such behaviour? Am I doing anything wrong? Is there some way how to avoid it and make the "Up next" feature working as expected?

Thanks,
Martin

### EDIT

I added some time pause between the requests (even minutes), but it didn't help.